# How can I generate a description list (dl) in Vue.js using v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

The v-for tag in vue is great, no doubt.

I have now the situation where I want to generate a description list such as [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#description-list-alignment). In this case I need to generate *two* DOM elements for each element in my array:

```js
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Description lists</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">A description list is perfect for defining terms.</dd>
```

Is there any (more or less elegant) way to do this with vue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`<template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt) tag with `v-for` to render a block of multiple elements

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { short: "1", long: "Long Description 1" },
        { short: "2", long: "Long Description 2" },
        { short: "3", long: "Long Description 3" },
        { short: "4", long: "Long Description 4" },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <dl class="row">
    <template v-for="data in items">
      <dt class="col-sm-3">{{data.short}}</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9">{{data.long}}</dd>
    </template>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: How to provide `key` attribute? the `template` cannot be keyed.

Comment: @HafezDivandari use a `<div v-for...>` wrapper, see my answer below

Comment: @HafezDivandari you can set the `key` attributes on both `dt` and `dd` elements: `<dt :key="data.short">...</dt><dd :key="data.short+'-value'">...</dd>`

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5 specification ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#Wrapping_name-value_groups_in_%3Cdiv%3E_elements)) allows for wrapping `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements in a `<div>` for microdata or styling purposes.  I'd recommend the following:

```
<dl class="row">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <dt class="col-sm-3">{{ item.key }}</dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-9">{{ item.value }}</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

This also handles the v-for requires a :key attribute.

Comment: To be exact, [MDN says the HTML 5.2 specification allows it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#specifications), not the HTML 5 specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<template v-for="item in items"></template>` which will only render the contents in your HTML and not a wrapping element. So you can generate two DOM elements for each element in an array.

Example :

```
 <template v-for="item in items">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Description lists</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9">A description list is perfect for defining terms.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Description lists</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9">A description list is perfect for defining terms.</dd>
    </dl>
 <template>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the `<template>` tag. As adiga's answer shows I can use this to generate multiple elements.